# jquery datetimepicker displaying i on the minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I wanted to add a datetime picker to my page. However, as can see below, it shows `i` instead of the minutes. Can you please help?

```js
$(function() {

  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM',
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: moment().toDate(),
    minDate: moment().toDate(),
    maxDate: moment().add(20, "days").toDate(),
  });

  $.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
    parseDate: function(date, format) {
      var d = moment(date, format);
      return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
    },
    formatDate: function(date, format) {
      return moment(date).format(format);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" />
```

Comment: He is using it to format the date inside the input

Comment: Also change format to `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'`. `MM` stands for month and `mm` minutes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i removed that and set my format to : d/m/Y H:i and it seems to work, but it dont show minutes, it just shows 00

Comment: That's what it should show. The time goes up in increments of 1 hour, on the hour.

Comment: any way to force it to show minutes...is a bit uncomfortable to tell users they can just enter the minutes

Answer (score 8):

You can add a `formatTime` property:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    // added formatTime 
    formatTime: 'HH:mm',
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: moment().toDate(),
    minDate: moment().toDate(),
    maxDate: moment().add(20, "days").toDate(),
  });

  $.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
    parseDate: function(date, format) {
      var d = moment(date, format);
      return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
    },
    formatDate: function(date, format) {
      return moment(date).format(format);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" />
```

Comment: thanks @AndroidNoobie, this seem to work fine, but now the time dont have actual minutes, is just 00

Comment: This is because of your use of `minDate`. It seems to be an open bug. There are a couple of workarounds discussed here: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1065

Answer (score 1):

The default value of format/formatTime/formatDate is:

```
format: 'Y/m/d H:i',
formatTime: 'H:i',
formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
```

according to:

> date formatter utility library that allows formatting date/time variables or Date objects using PHP DateTime format.

Hence, you need to change the previous values to:

```
format:'d/m/Y H:i',
formatDate: 'd/m/Y',
```

Moreover, if you want to change the selected value I would suggest to use the following callback instead of **$.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter**:

```
// when a date is changed
onChangeDateTime: function(date, input, event) {
```

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format:'d/m/Y H:i',
    formatDate: 'd/m/Y',
    lang:'en',
    startDate: moment().toDate(),
    minDate: moment().toDate(),
    maxDate: moment().add(20, "days").toDate(),
    onChangeDateTime: function(date, input, event) {
        input.val(moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" />
```